# Create a dropdown list of numbers in sequence

Tags: excel, validation, range

I want to create a dropdown list of numbers in sequence e.g. 1,2,3,...,n using data validation. I open the validation dialogue box, select List, but what do i type in the "Source" input box?

Im looking to using a function like the range() function in python to create the list. Is there such function in excel?

Comment: A list for Data Validation has to be either a hard-coded, comma-separated list entered directly into the Source box else a reference to a range of worksheet cells. Suggest you use the `SEQUENCE` function within a worksheet and use the resulting spilled range as the reference to enter in the Source box.

Comment: understood. This solves my conceptual misunderstanding towards data validation. Will go along with using the sequence function. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, fairly easily:

1. create a range that you'll be using for your data validation. A simple formula for this is: enter the first element of the range, then, in the next cell, enter the formua: '=previous_cell+1', and drag it until you have what you need.
2. Create the data validation as you described, and, in source, select your constructed range, but, instead of, let's say, A1-A20, select A:A (In the data validation source box, usually type a range of cells that contains the value that your dropdown needs, or the values as plain text, separated by comma). The list will be populated with the cells that contain a value and will be extended when the range will grow.

An alternative for the formula from step 1 is to use =Sequence(final_value) formula. This will generate a finite range on a row, that can be used in a data validation.

The correct formula is =SEQUENCE(row, [column]),where you specify the maximum value for the range. Example:
=sequence(10) will generate a range of 10 rows, containing the values from 1-10.
=sequence(3, 10) will generate 3 rows, with columns containing the values from 1-30. 1-10 for the 1st row, 11-20 for the 2nd and 21-30 for the last.

Comment: `=Sequence(start,stop)` isn't correct. The parameters are `=Sequence(rows,[columns],[start],[step])`

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer to better illustrate this functions and how it can be used for op's requests, without much details on the optional parameters

Comment: By selecting the entire column for the validation list, as per your step 2, an additional blank will appear at the end of the dropdown list, which may be undesirable. Better to create a dynamic range which excludes this additional blank.

Answer (score 0):

To create a comma-delimited list for your drop-down menu, click Source, input the text or numbers, and then click OK.

1st -> Choose the cells in which you want the lists to appear.

2nd -> Select **DATA** > **Data Validation** from the ribbon.

3rd -> Change **Allow** to **List** in the dialog box.

4th -> To create a comma-delimited list for your drop-down menu, click **Source**, input the text or numbers, and then click **OK**.